# Errors when using a WSDL based service with IBM Web Experience Factory

Tags: wsdl, websphere, factory, portlet

We are using IBM Web Experience Factory 7.0.1 for our project. In one of the models we are connecting to a WSDL based service. For that we are using Web Service Multiple Operation Builder. I have enabled testing support for the builder. But when I am testing by launching the model and try to invoke any methods I get the follwing error:

> An error has occurred.  The error message returned was: "Error in
>   method sd_WSMultiOpServicesGetOrdersGotoOperation. Error in method
>   sd_WSMultiOpServicesGetOrders_ShowResults. Error in method
>   getOrdersExecute. Error in method getOrders.invoke. Error in method
>   getOrders.invokeInternal. (404)Not Found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the Web Experience Factory (WEF) Web Service builders have an advanced input (checkbox) to tell them to log the requests and responses they're making/getting back.   Check that checkbox then save the model and run it again (redeploy if not auto-synching the project to the deployed WAR).   Then when you run the action that hits the web service, it should log additional debugging info into the deployed WAR's WEB-INF/logs folder in debugTracing.txt.   That should tell you what URL it's trying to hit with the web service that you're receiving the 404 error back from.

I hope that info helps,
..Mike Burati 
The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM.